# Changing the gap between two adjacent values on the x-axis in Seaborn pointplot

Tags: python, seaborn

When I was plotting with Seaborn pointplot, the gap between two adjacent values on the x-axis should be different, but now all of them are same, how could I change that?

For example, the gap between 5 and 7 is two, the other gaps are 1, but in the plot they all have the same length.

```
import seaborn as sns
tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
tips.loc[(tips['size'] == 6), 'size'] = 7
sns.pointplot('size', 'total_bill', 'sex', tips, dodge=True)
```

[image]

Comment: In a point plot the xaxis is a categorical axes, imagine it to be more like ["apples", "bananas", "cherry"], hence there is no "distance". Instead, you would probably want to use a matplotlib scatter or errorbar plot.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in Seaborn, the reason seems to be that it would interfere with the nested grouping from the `hue=` parameter, as indicated to in the [changelog describing why this functionality was removed from the `sns.violinplot`](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/179881fdb224279500eda9968fae3e5d1ed5c735/doc/releases/v0.6.0.txt#L27), which used to have a `positions=` keyword (as do `plt.boxplot`).

As indicated in the comments, it is possible to achieve the desired outcome using `plt.errorbar`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
tips.loc[(tips['size'] == 6), 'size'] = 7

# This is to avoid that the points from the different curves are in the
# exact same x-position (so that the error bars to not obfuscate each other)
offset_amount = 0.1
gender_groups = tips.groupby('sex')
num_groups = gender_groups.ngroups
lims =  num_groups * offset_amount / 2
offsets = np.linspace(-lims, lims, num_groups) 

# Calculate and plot the mean and error estimates.
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for offset, (gender_name, gender) in zip(offsets, gender_groups):
    means = gender.groupby('size')['total_bill'].mean()
    errs = gender.groupby('size')['total_bill'].sem() * 1.96 #95% CI
    ax.errorbar(means.index-offset, means, marker='o', yerr=errs, lw=2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `dodge` value in the arguments to a float, for example, dodge=2 would do the trick.

Comment: The answer as written is not clear. Please explain your idea in more detail.